# How to structure data for users based on date in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework, database-design, zend-db

I'm working on a zend project which has functionality based on user logged minutes. It needs to be able to generate reports based on date ranges. I'm hoping someone can help me figure out the best way to handle storing that information.

I am using a users table to handle all of the essential profile information. I would imagine the best case would be to link this to another table to track the minutes... im just not wrapping my mind around how it should lay out. I have seen some pages that suggest using columns in the database for the dates but that seems to me like it would become unmanageable quickly.

With the current site at 1500 users and multiple users submitting every day... im just not sure how id go about it.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Hmm, could you expand on what you mean by user's logged minutes? Do they do this manually, or is it "time spent on the site"?

Comment: It is manually entered. It is actually for tutors to enter time their students have read on any given day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach, based on what I think you're looking for:

Create a User_Session table containing a User_ID FK, a Start_Time, and an End_Time.   Write a new row to this table every time a user starts and ends a session.  You can grab these User_ID and Start_Time at login, and grab End_Time when the session ends or the user logs off.

Now you've got a historical table with [1500 users] x [number of sessions per day] which I'd call large but not unimaginably so. (Especially seeing how it's properly indexed and so forth.)    You can run queries against that table, something like SELECT User_ID, SUM(End_Time - Start_Time) so to speak, against whatever date ranges you need.

To control the table size, you could in turn store these aggregated values (User_ID, MMYY, Num_Minutes) and truncate the source table on some set schedule.   Storing calculated fields may not preferable to having the normalized data on hand, though.  So maybe don't go that route until you've determined that the source table size is a big issue.

Just one of many ways, and oversimplified for clarity's sake.

Comment: That makes sense. That's also explains part of the functionality that I've got scheduled out for a later date so thanks for that as well.

Comment: Another question for you if I may... I am somewhat newer to a database of this size at what point would you say the database is getting "too big"? I know this will all depend on file size, the server etc. Im just looking for a general idea of when you could see it causing issues.

Comment: 100,000+ rows should be no problem.   The key considerations are a well-designed table (you're just storing the necessary keys and no superfluous data) and indexing (choosing proper indexes against the fields you intend to query.)   Of course server speed and file size matters, but that's not what'll burn ya nine times out of ten.

Comment: To stir it up a bit more, remember there are two sides of the 'performance' question:  your web application has to WRITE to the table quickly, and your reports need to SELECT adequately quickly.   The former is probably more important for the health of your site (except for the guy running the report of course.)

Comment: We have tables in our database with on the order of millions of rows. Mostly logging data, not used often, but good for historical analysis.